# Is there a way I could declare my preloads in a less error prone way

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a bunch of preloads to preload nested relations

```
func Companies(db *database.Database) fiber.Handler {
    return func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        companies := new([]model.Company)

        result := db.Preload("Relation.Addresses").
            Preload("Relation.Contacts").
            Preload("Relation.People").
            Preload("Relation.BankAccounts").
            Preload(clause.Associations).
            Find(&companies)

        if result.Error != nil {
            return c.JSON(responseKit.RecordNotFoundError())
        }

        return c.JSON(responseKit.RecordsFoundSuccess(*companies, len(*companies)))
    }
}
```

These are my structs

```
type Company struct {
    PrivateGormModel
    Name     string   `json:"name"`
    Relation Relation `gorm:"polymorphic:Owner;" json:"relation"`
}

type Relation struct {
    PrivateGormModel
    OwnerID      uint          `json:"ownerID"`
    OwnerType    string        `json:"ownerType"`
    Addresses    []Address     `gorm:"polymorphic:Owner;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;" json:"addresses"`
    Contacts     []Contact     `gorm:"polymorphic:Owner;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;" json:"contacts"`
    People       []Person      `gorm:"polymorphic:Owner;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;" json:"people"`
    BankAccounts []BankAccount `gorm:"polymorphic:Owner;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;" json:"bankAccounts"`
}
```

Which I found here and works

https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html

But I think this code is error prone because I pass the field names as a string and the field names might change in the future. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with reflection package. See this part of code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type StructA struct {}

type StructB struct {}
type StructC struct {}

func GetTypeName(data interface{}) string {
    if data == nil {
        return ""
    }
    
    refVal := reflect.TypeOf(data)
    
    if refVal.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        return ""
    }
    
    return refVal.Name();
}


func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", StructA{})
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", StructB{})  
    fmt.Println(GetTypeName(StructC{})) 
    fmt.Println(GetTypeName(StructB{})) 
    fmt.Println(GetTypeName(StructA{})) 
    fmt.Println(GetTypeName("ABC")) 
    fmt.Println(GetTypeName(nil))   
}
```

It produces the following output:

```
main.StructA
main.StructB{}
StructC
StructB
StructA
```

It should help you be compile-time safer, but you need to remember it is a little slower